# How to make a default GSMapView InfoWindowOfMarker UIView frame hidden in Swift 4?

Tags: swift

I have a programmatically created UIView that I decided to use later. However, it is now called in the navigation logic and I don't want to change the logic because I will introduce this preview in the second release. The problem is that I am stuck with a default frame which I cannot move beyond the screen or change size to zero or make hidden.

Here's the class in code and I attach the picture of this ugly white default frame I need to somehow hide. I tried a lot of options with constraints, transparency and so on, but it is still there. Can anybody give advice?

```
class PointPreview: UIView {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
   }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Try this: backgroundColor = .clear

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried bringing the other view(looks like a map guessing from your image) in front of the white view?

You can do that like this:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController{
   override func viewDidLoad() {
      let pointPreview = PointPreview()
      let otherView = UIView()
      self.view.addSubview(otherView)
      self.view.addSubview(pointPreview)
      self.view.bringSubviewToFront(otherView) //this makes the otherView(map) go in front of the pointPreview
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must be adding this frame to the parent view somewhere using the `addSubview(_:)` method.

You can just comment out that line. The view won't be added and it won't show.

Comment: I don't. This frame is returned when I tap a map marker. I removed everything I could but I have to return the view to keep the logic I need. The view is initialized with this default frame that I can't hide